# Centre text vertically in anchor whilst filling space

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I'm creating a set of tabs - there are various rules I need to follow - one of which is to allow line wrapping on the anchor text. The current solution I have involves table-cell to achieve what I need:

[image]

As you can see, this works. The tabs are centered horizontally and text is centered vertically, however, there is still an issue that I need to resolve. The yellow area represents the anchor and the red, the LI (table-cell). What I need is for the anchor to fill the space available in its parent whilst keeping the text vertically aligned - in other words, the whole thing should be yellow.

Here's the code I have so far:

```css
   ul.fixed-tabs 
    {
        display: table;
        table-layout:fixed;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    
    ul.fixed-tabs li
    {
        display:table-cell;
        min-width:16rem;
        max-width:26.4rem;
        width:50%;
    
        height:4.8rem;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    
    ul.fixed-tabs li a
    {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content-tabs">
  <ul class="fixed-tabs text-tabs two-up">
    <li href="#"><a>Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy long longer longest</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

UPDATE

Here's the latest output using BaTmaN's fiddle.

[image]

Comment: If you create a working example so people can experiment with your CDD you might get better answers :)

Comment: Is it ok to change the HTML markup if required?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ul.fixed-tabs li a
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    height:100%;
}
```

or appropriate padding you need

Comment: Can't use padding - the lines can wrap text.

Comment: it is best way to not use white-space:nowrap,

but if you want same then go for height:100%

Answer (score 0):

Add `height :100%` .   Now everything in the anchor is yellow.

```
 ul.fixed-tabs li a
{
  height:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
  background:yellow;
}
```

for demonstration I have added the screenshot. Links in yellow and non link in red.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/nomipavojo/2/edit

To make text vertically center. Add  `line-height:80px;` additionally to your `ul.fixed-tabs li a` css

> Text aligned vertically middle by adding vertical-align, table-cell and height properties.

```
ul.fixed-tabs li a
{
 height:4.8rem;
   width:26.4rem;
  text-align:center;
  background:yellow;
  display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/guqahufavi/3/edit

[image]

> Width in px instead of rem.

```
ul.fixed-tabs li
{
    display:table-cell;
    min-width:160px;
    max-width:264px;
    height:4.8rem;
  width:50%;
    vertical-align:middle;
  background :red;
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.fixed-tabs li a
{
  height:4.8rem;
  min-width:264px;
  max-width:264px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
  background:yellow;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nuqiderado/2/edit

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the solution you suggested won't work - as you will see from my illustration - the line can wrap, so I can't just add a fixed line height.

Comment: Still not there - if you apply a width, the overall width is no longer respected. In the LI table-cell we set a max-width, not a width. On short lines,  the cell is still 26.4rem.

Comment: still doesn't work - Firstly, I removed the third LI from your fiddle (serves no purpose), then adjusted your min/max to 160px/264px (what my rems equate to), then ran it - Iv'e added the result to the post above. You can see that the smaller of the 2 no longer flexes in line with the long text.